# In agriculture, what do you call a section within an orchard?

Tags: spanish

I'm a software developer and I like to have my code in english.
I'm currently developing a software for fruit exporters and packing plants.

There are growers, orchards and **orchards sections**.

In spanish these are: productores, huertos and cuarteles.

Is there a word for "cuarteles"? (orchard section)

An orchard may have many sections. Typically, in each section you only have one commodity/variety (eg. apples/fuji)

Google translate gives me "barracks" but that is in a military context, I think.

Comment: Maybe this way: growers, farms, and orchards; a farm could be made up of many orchards.

Comment: I would call it a *section*.

Comment: Has it occurred to you to ask your (potential) clients? If you are lacking familiarity, much less expertise, with the domain you are working in, expect larger issues than this going forward.

Comment: @mickeyf It sounds like the fruit exporters might be working in Spanish (in which the OP knows the terminology); only the OP's code is actually in English.

Comment: @1006a is right. Most of the users are spanish speakers and what I show to them has no problem. But the code is in english. I like GEdgar suggestion...

Comment: On an entirely different note, "software* is uncountable. Therefore, you should say, "I'm currently developing *software* for …" (no article in front of "software"). Or, if you want to include the fact that it's just one thing of that kind, you could say, "I'm currently developing *a piece of* software for …"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Cuartel* is related to the English word *quarter*.  One sense of one meaning of *quarter* is indeed barracks, but another is an area of a city (exemplified by Latin Quarter).  Spanish has this meaning too:"Cuartel, subdivisión administrativa de algunas municipalidades de gran tamaño." according to [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuartel).

This suggests using a simple *section* (as in your question) *area* or *zone*.  These terms reflect the man-made or arbitrary boundary of the sub-orchard*, while a *grove* might be expected to be surrounded by open space, and a *stand* of trees would be obvious to an observer (like a stand of oaks in a beech wood).  A stand of red delicious in an orchard of golden delicious would fit this sense -- for a few weeks of the year.

*Another term you could use if desperate

Answer (score 5):

You could use **grove** instead of an orchard section.

> a small wood, orchard, or group of trees.

[Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=grove)

Answer (score 5):

A section of trees within a larger, wooded area is called a '**stand**' of trees.

This citation is the title of a [technical paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264837716303507) about reforestation programs :

> A **stand** of trees does not a forest make: Tree plantations and forest transitions